# Eclipse referencing folders inside a Jar file

Tags: java, jar

In my Java project I have a folder like the one below, where I put inside some icons that I'm going to use with JTree library.

[image]

When I run the Jar outside Eclipse, I cannot see my icons.
If I open my Jar with archive utility, I cannot see the folder inside it. I also tried to add different folders and they are never referenced inside the final Jar.
So, is there a way to reference the folders in the Jar file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that Eclipse knows that while building the Jar it has to include the newFolder inside the Jar. You can do that in Eclipse by following the below step in :

- click `project -> properties -> Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder` and select the new folder you just created.

Now create you Jar and you will see your folder in the Jar.

Answer (score 1):

Either move the folder (myFolder) into src directory or mark it as a source folder.